# ¿Cómo generar una acción en un list Item personalizado desde otra activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, json, listview, jsonobject

Verán, este es el código de la clase del list item personalizado

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
private ArrayList<PlanAlimento> list = new ArrayList<PlanAlimento>();
private Context context;

public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<PlanAlimento> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return list.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return list.get(pos).getJaula().getId(); //Realmente descono
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
    }

    TextView listItemtxtTitulo = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView_txtTitulo);
    TextView listItemtxtSubtitulo = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView_txtSubtitulo);
    listItemtxtTitulo.setText(list.get(position).getJaula().getTipo() + " " + list.get(position).getJaula().getNumero());
    listItemtxtSubtitulo.setText(list.get(position).getComentarios());

    Animation scaleUp, scaleDown;
    Button btnComida = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.listView_btnComida);
    Button btnLimpiar = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.listView_btnLimpiar);
    scaleUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(view.getContext(), R.anim.scale_up);
    scaleDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(view.getContext(), R.anim.scale_down);

    btnComida.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                btnComida.startAnimation(scaleUp);
            }

            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                btnComida.startAnimation(scaleDown);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    btnLimpiar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                btnLimpiar.startAnimation(scaleUp);
            }

            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                btnLimpiar.startAnimation(scaleDown);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Y lo ejecuto desde esta clase (He sacado elementos de la clase que no van al caso con el fin de que el código sea más fácil de comprender):

```
public class ActivityMantenimiento extends Activity {
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
private RequestQueue request;
private StringRequest stringRequest;

Button btnComida;
Button btnLimpieza;

ArrayList<PlanAlimento> listaTareas;
ListView listViewTareasMantenimiento;

PlanAlimento unPlan;
CustomAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    request = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    iniciar();
    listaTareas = new ArrayList<PlanAlimento>();
    listarTareasMantenimiento();

    /*btnComida.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            agregarMantenimientoComida();
        }
    });*/

    /*btnLimpieza.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            agregarMantenimientoLimpieza();
        }
    });*/
}

private void agregarMantenimientoComida(){
   //Código casi identico al de agregarMantenimientoLimpieza
}

private void agregarMantenimientoLimpieza(){
    try{
        String ip = "https://pruebahostreserva.000webhostapp.com";
        String url = ip + "/wsJSONAltaMantenimientoJaula.php?" + "&idJaula=" + unPlan.getJaula().getId() + "&idUsuario=" + unPlan.getUsuario().getId() +
                "&tipoMantenimiento=limpiezaMJ";

        url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
        stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if(response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("registro")){
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityMantenimiento.this, "Ingresado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btnLimpieza.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
        request.add(stringRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(ActivityMantenimiento.this, "Ha ocurrido un error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void listarTareasMantenimiento(){
    String ip = "https://pruebahostreserva.000webhostapp.com";
    String url = ip + "/wsJSONListarPlanesAlimento.php";

    try{
        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                listaTareas = new ArrayList<>();
                Jaula unaJaula = null;
                Usuario unUsuario = null;
                JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("planAlimento");

                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= json.length(); i++) {
                        unPlan = new PlanAlimento();
                        unaJaula = new Jaula();
                        unUsuario = new Usuario();

                        JSONObject jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);

                        unaJaula.setId(jsonObject.optInt("idJaula"));
                        unaJaula.setTipo(jsonObject.optString("tipoJaula"));
                        unaJaula.setNumero(jsonObject.optInt("numeroJaula"));

                        unUsuario.setId(4);

                        unPlan.setId(jsonObject.optInt("idPlanAlim"));
                        unPlan.setJaula(unaJaula);
                        unPlan.setUsuario(unUsuario);
                        unPlan.setFechaDesde(jsonObject.optString("fechaDesdePlanAlim"));
                        unPlan.setFechaHasta(jsonObject.getString("fechaHastaPlanAlim"));
                        unPlan.setComentarios(jsonObject.getString("comentariosPlanAlim"));

                        listaTareas.add(unPlan);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(listaTareas != null && listaTareas.size() > 0){
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    }
}

private void cargarLista(){
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(listaTareas, this);
    listViewTareasMantenimiento.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void iniciar(){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mantenimiento_jaulas);
    listViewTareasMantenimiento = findViewById(R.id.ActivityMantenimientoJaulas_list);
}
```

}

La cuestión es que desde la clase CustomAdapter no sé cómo podría capturar los datos de la clase Mantenimiento para generar la consulta a la BDD. Y si quiero iniciar los botones desde la clase Mantenimiento se rompe todo (Ya que tiene sentido debido a que pertenecen a otro XML).

En síntesis, los botones pertenecen a otro XML ya que necesitaba hacer el List personalizado. Pero al ejecutar la clase Mantenimiento (donde carga la lista y toma el CustomAdapter como adaptador de la lista) no me permite utilizar los botones (ya que necesito capturar algunos datos de la clase Mantenimiento para ejecutar la consulta).

Agradezco cualquier guía, realmente me encuentro perdida y revuelta en cómo hacerle.